# facebook developers page likes

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying using facebook developers to get page likes. until v2.5 I used to send the giving request and get total likes:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/{page-id}?fields=likes&access_token=
```

but now with the new v2.6 when i send the same request i'm getting a different result that isn't total likes of the page.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/{page-id}?fields=likes&access_token=
```

how can i get those likes using v2.6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field `likes` was renamed to `fan_count` from v2.5 to v2.6, see

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_6

The call is now

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/{page-id}?fields=fan_count&access_token={access_token}
```